# iOS Basic Request to webservice

Tags: ios, json, http, request

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a good tutorial or possibly answer this question.

I have some JSON to be returned on my web server

```
{
first_name: "Joe";
last_name: "Smith";
department: "Human Resources";
}
```

How do I make a http request to get this information at the click of a button and display as text on the iphone.?

Complete newbie so please 'dumb' down.

Comment: check this out http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a jsonviewcontroller class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JSONViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
{
    NSString *label;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
- (IBAction)getTop10AlbumAction:(id)sender;


@end
```

then in implementation class:-

```
#import "JSONViewController.h"

@interface JSONViewController ()
{
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSString *category;    
}

@end

@implementation JSONViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed with Error");
}
```

this is the place where actual parsing happens, we fetch the title of albums from respective dictionary and arrays. to understand this first go to this link http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json this is the json viewer which shows the structure of the content that we are going to access. dont panic! its really easy if u try parsing some json urls

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *feed=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSArray *arrayOfEntry=[feed objectForKey:@"entry"];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayOfEntry) {
        NSDictionary *title=[dict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *label=[title objectForKey:@"label"];
        [array addObject:label];
    }

[[self myTableView]reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return[array count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //clear background color
    [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //set cell text
    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //set cell accessory type
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

here we specify the itunes url that we are going to parse and make connection request

```
- (IBAction)getTop10AlbumAction:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json"];    
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    [[self myTableView]reloadData];
}
@end
```

i hope i have made it clear enough!

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you two different tutorials:

1. Creating a simple interface. Here is a sample from Apple that have a button and a text displayed: [iOS Button - Label sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
2. Insert into controller code (i.e. `changeGreeting:`) the code that calls the webservice: [iOS JSON Webservice tutorial](http://reins.altervista.org/wordpress/ios-json-webservices/)